# JMeter Ramp Up Period

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am carrying out load-testing for one of the process.
Scenario is every 20 seconds 10 users are logging into the system until i have total users say 1000.

How do I specify this in Jmeter?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin for stepping profile: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup